# User's nick name

Tags: google-app-engine

I have 5 types of objects in an application let's say A, B , C, D, E

The application lists objects of all type, where it shows their name, created user and other Info.

Now, to be able to show user's name in every object listing, I have some options

1) Store the USER entity key in every object and then when I retrieve say list of Objects of type A, then also retrieve user's keys and their names and then attach them to objects of type A

2) When a object of any type is created, also store a property "Name" which will be name of user who created the object (Yikes approach IMHO, what if the user changes his name later ;)

But I am not convinced both ways above are right! I am looking for an answer, from someone who might have faced similar problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you've already answered yourself, option 2 is not advisable, since an user can change his/her username, and cascading the change (manually) in the DataStore is not a good choice.

Comment: But I am not happy with way 1 too, because, every time I need to get the list of Objects-A, then scan through each's user Key and then get their nick names. If the types I have increase from A-E to more, I have more code to write. Of course I can make it a abstract method and pull to all processors or something like that, but somehow I feel things can be better? Or Am I thinking just too relational ;)?

Comment: Why scan the user keys? You can find directly a record by its user id. What I'd do is write a DAO, that among other methods retrieves the user by id and stores it in memcache, so the next time you don't have to query it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ReferenceProperty

Example from the link:

```
class Author(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class Story(db.Model):
    author = db.ReferenceProperty(Author)

story = db.get(story_key)
author_name = story.author.name

author = db.get(author_key)
stories_by_author = author.story_set.get()
```

The option1 can be done easily with ReferenceProperty. 
No extra code needed if the performance is not your major concern.

I haven't use java on Google App Engine, 
but google app engine did support object relationship you needed as well.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html#Owned_One_to_One_Relationships

Comment: I forgot to mention this was in Java, does that make difference to solution? I have no clue of Python, but I understood the concept.

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html#Owned_One_to_Many_Relationships more references!